# A ratio to measure 'roundedness' of planar convex regions

Tags: discrete-geometry, convex-geometry, computational-geometry

Ref: [A center of convex planar regions based on chords](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/396579/a-center-of-convex-planar-regions-based-on-chords)

The above discussion quotes the definition of 'centralness coefficient' and defines a center of a planar convex region. 1/2 is the least possible value of centralness coefficient among all convex planar regions. This value holds for all triangles. In this post, we consider another quantity to measure how 'rounded' a convex region is and partitions of convex regions based on this quantity. Note that a thin rectangle has centralness (it is centrally symmetric) but is not very rounded.

**Question:** For every point P in the interior of a planar convex region
C, consider the ratio: distance from P to closest point on the boundary / distance from P to the farthest boundary point. Let us call this the *depth ratio* of P. Consider the point(s) in C that maximize the depth ratio (*'depth center'*, say)and note the value of this ratio there. How does one partition a planar convex region into n convex pieces such that every piece has the same maximum depth ratio?

**Remarks:** For any C, the depth center(s) appear to lie on the medial axis. Even when C is a triangle, we don't have a unique depth center but the incenter seems to be *a* solution. Unlike the centralness coefficient, the maximum depth ratio of a triangle region goes to 0 as the triangle tends to become degenerate.

**Further Question:** Are there any other properties that are shared by the pieces in a partition that gives pieces with same maximum depth ratio? And continuing from [On cutting convex regions with average values of quantities minimized](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/408968/on-cutting-convex-regions-with-average-values-of-quantities-minimized), one can ask if maximizing the minimum of the max depth ratio among pieces necessarily makes it equal across pieces.